# Visual Studio 2010 pauses for minutes when opening project properties

Tags: visual-studio-2010

When using Visual Studio 2010, occasionally it will pause for many minutes when I right click on a project and click properties. I originally thought that this was due to Code Contracts settings, but I still get it occasionally with these turned off.

Any people having the same issue, or know how I could go about debugging what is causing this?

Comment: Do you use any source control (like Team Foundation Server) in your solution? Do you have any extensions installed?

Comment: Yes I do. It has occurred to me that one of them could be causing the the problem, but reproducing the issue, let along doing it between installs, would be practically impossible.

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by a few things, so try these steps to diagnose/resolve.

1. Disable all visual studio extensions (or 1 by one until you no longer see the issue)
2. Un-link the project from any source control integration like SVN (if you have the Visual studio SVN add in) or TFS
3. Copy the solution folder to another drive/external drive to see if it may be related to the specific location it's stored on your current drive.
4. Copy the solution to another system of similar configuration to see it is specific to the solution/project or just your machine/installation.
5. Ensure you have Service Pack 1 of Visual Studio installed.
6. If there are any 'Web References' in the project remove them to see if the problem stops.